How to query on TypeORM with the duplicate key on AND condition in find()
  const salesList = await this.salesRepository.find({
    where: {
      productId: productId,
      productId: Not(0)
    }
  });

Based on the above code, how to use the same key for the query?
It throws me error 'An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.
'
appreciate every helps. thanks.

In JavaScript, an object cannot have multiple properties with the same name. You can combine conditions using And operator if your ORM supports it, or construct the query differently.

where: {
productId: Not(0),
and: [{ productId: productId }]
}

 import { And,Not } from "typeorm";
 const salesList = await this.salesRepository.find({
   where: [
     { productId: productId },
     { productId: Not(0) }
   ]
 });




 import { And,Not } from "typeorm";
 const salesList = await this.salesRepository.find({
   where: {
     productId: And(productId, Not(0))
   }
 });



